# Median of arbitrary datapoint around index - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, median

I've been using the `findpeaks` function with great success to detect peaks in my signal. My next step is to clean these identified peaks, for which I have the indices.

My goal is to calculate the median of Y data points before and Y data points after a given index and replace whatever values (noise) there are with these new values (the calculated median).

Something like this:

```
%  points before, peak, points after
%        ↓         ↓         ↓
x = [1, 2, 3, 1,   34,   3, 2, 1, 3]
```

Calculate the median of the 4 data points preceding and following my peak the peak of `34`...

Median of `[1,2,3,1,3,2,1,3]` is `2`.

Replace my peak with this new value:

```
% Replaced peak with surrounding median
%                  ↓
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 1,  2,  3, 2, 1, 3]
```

Any suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: Take a look at the [median filter / running median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). If I understand correctly, this should solve exactly your problem. The corresponding MATLAB function is [`medfilt1()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In fact I wan't to use a specific window size around an index to calculate the median, and than replace the value at the index with this median value. I don't think medfilt1() can help with this.

Comment: Doesn't `findpeaks` detect 3 as a peak as well (local maxima)? How are you going to incorporate that?

Comment: @Oiko: `medfilt1()` does not compute the median but performs *median filtering* with a window length that can be specified via the second argument of the function. However, now I see that you only want to do this for specific indices of you array. I guess you'll have to do it manually. Something like `x(idx_max) = median(x(idx_max-N:idx_max+N))`.

Comment: @Sardar Usama: In fact the values around the peaks are considerably different (the example above is quite simplified). If, after this operation values around the peak are somewhat high and detectable by the findpeaks function, i'll replace the surrounding data points with the median value also:

Comment: @applesoup: that's it. I just need to perform the operation within a window around my indices. I'll give your suggestion a try ;)

Comment: @Oiko: Give it a try. The answer by jodag should lead to identical results. While jodag's solution is elegant and requires less typing, my approach should have lower computational requirements.

Comment: Both methods work quite well :)
Your way is significantly faster, a few ms versus almost 9s.

Comment: @applesoup: Any suggestion on how to change the adjacent 5 values around the peak to the calculated median? I'm struggling with this operation...

cheers

Comment: @Oiko: The last step in my answer addresses exactly this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the peaks and replace them with the results of [`medfilt1()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html?searchHighlight=medfilt1&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)

```
[~,idx]=findpeaks(x);
if ~isempty(idx)
    m = medfilt1(x,9);
    x(idx) = m(idx);
end
```

Comment: Straightforward!

Comment: @jodag: Any suggestion on how to change the adjacent 5 values around the peak to the calculated median? I'm struggling with this operation...

cheers

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You would need to post another question to define the problem better but if I make some assumptions then consider `x(idx-1) = m(idx); x(idx+1) = m(idx);` to set the 2 adjacent values around the peak to the calculated median at the peak. You would need to ensure `idx+/-1` doesn't go out of bounds, ex `x(max(1,idx-1)) = m(idx)` or `x(idx(idx-1 > 0)-1) = m(idx(idx-1 > 0));`.

Comment: @jodag: Thanks for the help! I've just posted a new question (link bellow) to try to clarify what I need. I don't fully understand your suggestion above.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377438/replace-values-around-index-matlab

Comment: @Oiko you keep insisting that this code that works for everyone else only replaces the first index for you. I confirm it also works fine in Octave. Can you please confirm what your issue was?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is most efficient to process each peak individually. I'll demonstrate in a step-by-step manner in the following.

Take the neighborhood of each peak

```
x(idx_max-N:idx_max+N)
```

with `N` the number of elements to the left and right of the peak, respectively. The median of the neighborhood around each peak can be computed by using MATLAB's [`median()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) function:

```
median(x(idx_max-N:idx_max+N))
```

Now, you can replace either only the element at the peak position with the median of the neighborhood:

```
x(idx_max) = median(x(idx_max-N:idx_max+N))
```

or easily replace all elements of the neighborhood with the median value:

```
x(idx_max-N:idx_max+N) = median(x(idx_max-N:idx_max+N))
```

(Note that [scalar expansion](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/assign-and-access-vector-and-matrix-values.html) is used in the last example to assign a scalar value to multiple elements of an array.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 
In fact i did just what you suggested and I'm not able to replace the values **around** the peak. I'm only able to change the value at the peak. By selecting the indices around my target data point (peak) no change is applied to the signal....

Comment: That is strange. I tried it and it works (with MATLAB 2014a). Do you get an error instead?

Comment: You are right. Sorry.... I had checked a random peak before and this code only performs the operation for the first index. Any idea on how to make it work on all indices? If I only change the peak value x(idx), it performs the operation on all indices. When selecting a window around the peak x(idx**-N**:idx**+N**) = ... it does it for the first index only.

Comment: If I understand correctly (`idx` is an array of maximum indices?) you will have to loop over all elements of `idx`: `for cur_idx = idx; x(cur_idx-N:cur_idx+N) = median(x(cur_idx-N:cur_idx+N)); end`

Comment: correct, idx is an array of indices of the maxima. It still only changes the values around the first index (peak)...

Comment: Okay, I don't understand why that happens. If you post your code (e.g., via [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/)) I will try to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377438/replace-values-around-index-matlab/47379639#47379639