# Replace +/- values around index - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

Following this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368216/median-of-arbitrary-datapoint-around-index-matlab?noredirect=1#comment81692278_47368216) and the precious help I got from it, I've reached to the following issue:

Using indices of detected peaks and having computed the median of my signal +/-3 datapoints around these peaks, I need to replace my signal in a +/-5 window around the peak with the previously computed median.

I'm only able replace the datapoint at the peak with the median, but not the surrounding +/-5 data points...see figure. Black = original peak; Yellow = data point at peak changed to the median of +/-3 datapoints around it.

[Original peak and changed peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUM0k.png)

Unfortunately I have not been able to make it work by following suggestions on the previous question.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Cheers,
M

Comment: data[idx-5:idx+5] = median

Comment: @JLev: Thanks. Unfortunately I did not work with the square brackets...

I've tried the following: data(idx-5:idx+5) = median(data(idx-3:idx+3)) to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it really is () and not []. What do you mean by no avail? You get an error? Results are not what you expected?

Comment: Actually, the code I used works, but only for the first value... any suggestion on how to perform the operation for al indices?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: data(idx-5:idx+5) = median(data(idx-3:idx+3))
Only the values around the first index are replaced by the computed median.

Comment: How do you compute idx? how many values are in idx?

Comment: idx is the output of the findpeaks() function. It has 1529 values.

Comment: `for index = idx
data(index:index+5) = median(data(index-3:index+3));
end`

Comment: for index = idx; x(index-5:index+5) = median(x(index-3:index+3)); end;                                                                                                               just tried this a few minutes ago. Still only the first value is changed...

Comment: @Oiko you keep insisting that this code that works for everyone else only replaces the first index for you. I confirm it also works fine in Octave. Can you please confirm what your issue was? What you reported seems irreproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the following. Given the array

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 35 5 4 3 2 1 0]
```

you want to replace `35` and surrounding +/- 5 entries with the median of `3,4,5,35,5,4,3`, which is `4`, so the resulting array should be

```
x = [0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0]
```

---

Following my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368216) an intuitive approach is to simply replace the neighbors with the median value by offsetting the indicies. This can be accomplished as follows

```
[~,idx]=findpeaks(x);
med_sz = 3;    % Take the median with respect to +/- this many neighbors
repl_sz = 5;   % Replace neighbors +/- this distance from peak
if ~isempty(idx)
    m = medfilt1(x,med_sz*2+1);
    N = numel(x);
    for offset = -repl_sz:repl_sz
        idx_offset = idx + offset;
        idx_valid = idx_offset >= 1 & idx_offset <= N;
        x(idx_offset(idx_valid)) = m(idx(idx_valid));
    end
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid loops, an equivalent loopless implementation is

```
[~,idx]=findpeaks(x);
med_sz = 3;
repl_sz = 5;
if ~isempty(idx)
    m = medfilt1(x,med_sz*2+1);
    idx_repeat = repmat(idx,repl_sz*2+1,1);
    idx_offset = idx_repeat + repmat((-repl_sz:repl_sz)',1,numel(idx));
    idx_valid = idx_repeat >= 1 & idx_repeat <= numel(x);
    idx_repeat = idx_repeat(idx_valid);
    idx_offset = idx_offset(idx_valid);
    x(idx_offset) = m(idx_repeat);
end
```